# Jenkins-selenium webdriver-chrome driver

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am able to run selenium webdriver backed script triggering ant via command prompt.

**Test script run successfully, and Junit test result generated with screenshot in the report.**

> The same script when run on Jenkins, chrome browser not launched, build success, however Junit test report incomplete, the screenshot doesn't appear. looks like the action in the script not being perform as well.

See log below from Jenkins console output for the job.

My test PC`s OS is windows XP and chrome ver30. Same script running fine with IE and Firefox browser when run via Jenkins (able to see browser getting launch and performing action.pls assist.

Log info:

```
    [testng] log4j: reset attribute= "false".
       [testng] log4j: Threshold ="null".
       [testng] log4j: Level value for root is  [debug].
       [testng] log4j: root level set to DEBUG
       [testng] log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
       [testng] log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [INFO].
       [testng] log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
       [testng] log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1} : %m%n].
       [testng] log4j: Adding appender named [std-out] to category [root].
       [testng] log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender]
       [testng] log4j: Setting property [file] to [debug.log].
       [testng] log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [50MB].
       [testng] log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
       [testng] log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [DEBUG].
       [testng] log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
       [testng] log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1} : %m%n].
       [testng] log4j: setFile called: debug.log, true
       [testng] log4j: setFile ended
       [testng] log4j: Adding appender named [debug-out] to category [root].
       [testng] 19:04:22,875 INFO  BaseSeleniumTest : total test methods found:1
       [testng] 19:04:22,875 INFO  BaseSeleniumTest :  
       [testng] CHECKING IF ANY WEBDRIVERS HAVE NOT PREVIOUSLY BEEN ADDED:
       [testng] 19:04:22,875 INFO  BaseSeleniumTest : BROWSER NOT PRESENT SO ADDING BROWSER:CH
       [testng] 19:04:22,875 INFO  WebDriverSupplier : Requested to ADD a webbrowser supplier for :CH
       [testng] 19:04:22,875 INFO  WebDriverSupplier : ADDED webbrowser supplier for :CH the complete map now contains the following:[CH]
       [testng] [TestNG] Running:
       [testng]   Selenium Regression Tests
       [testng] 
       [testng] 19:04:23,328 INFO  BaseSeleniumTest : SET UP REPORTER FOR  test1
       [testng] 19:04:23,359 INFO  BaseSeleniumTest : RETURN:1
       [testng] Starting ChromeDriver (v2.3) on port 54671
       [testng] org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary


    [testng]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.3,platform=Windows NT 5.1 SP3 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
       [testng] Command duration or timeout: 875 milliseconds
       [testng] Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01'
       [testng] System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_10'
       [testng] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
       [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
       [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
       [testng]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
       [testng]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
       [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
       [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
       [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
       [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
       [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
       [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
       [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:161)
       [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
       [testng]     at com.examples.core.WebDriverSupplier$1.get(WebDriverSupplier.java:54)
       [testng]     at com.examples.core.WebDriverSupplier$1.get(WebDriverSupplier.java:39)
       [testng]     at com.examples.tests.test1.testMethod(test1.java:24)
       [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       [testng]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       [testng]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       [testng]     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
       [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
       [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
       [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
       [testng]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
       [testng]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
       [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
       [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
       [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
       [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
       [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
       [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
       [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
       [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
       [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
       [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
       [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
       [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
       [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
       [testng] 19:04:26,421 INFO  BaseSeleniumTest : finished running 1/1 DECLARED TESTS against 1/1 BROWSERS defined
       [testng] 19:04:26,421 INFO  BaseSeleniumTest : finished TEST SUITE 1 out of 1 to run


testng] Starting ChromeDriver (v2.3) on port 52079
   [testng] 
   [testng] ===============================================
   [testng] Selenium Regression Tests
   [testng] Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
   [testng] Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
   [testng] ===============================================
   [testng] 
   [testng] The tests failed.

    run-junit-report:
         [exec] Buildfile: C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\myeg maintenance\Selenium-Regression-Project-master\RegressionTestHarness\build.xml
         [exec] 
         [exec] report:
         [exec] [junitreport] Processing C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\myeg maintenance\Selenium-Regression-Project-master\RegressionTestHarness\results\junitreports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\null943067594
         [exec] [junitreport] Loading stylesheet C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\myeg maintenance\Selenium-Regression-Project-master\RegressionTestHarness\xsl\junit-frames.xsl
         [exec] [junitreport] Transform time: 1219ms
         [exec] [junitreport] Deleting: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\null943067594
         [exec] 
         [exec] check.archive.results:
         [exec] 
         [exec] archive.results:
         [exec]      [echo] Archiving results....
         [exec]      [copy] Copying 40 files to C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\myeg maintenance\Selenium-Regression-Project-master\RegressionTestHarness\archives\results_09-10-2013-0704
         [exec] 
         [exec] copy.images:
         [exec]      [copy] Copying 4 files to C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\myeg maintenance\Selenium-Regression-Project-master\RegressionTestHarness\results\junitreports\com\examples\images
         [exec]      [copy] Copying 8 files to C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\myeg maintenance\Selenium-Regression-Project-master\RegressionTestHarness\results\junitreports\com\examples\images\media
         [exec]    [delete] Deleting directory C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\myeg maintenance\Selenium-Regression-Project-master\RegressionTestHarness\results\junitreports\com\examples\images\templates
         [exec]    [delete] Deleting directory C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\myeg maintenance\Selenium-Regression-Project-master\RegressionTestHarness\SeleniumTestResults
         [exec] 
         [exec] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
         [exec] Total time: 2 seconds

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    Total time: 19 seconds
    Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
    [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
    [htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\myeg maintenance to C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\myeg maintenance\builds\2013-10-09_19-04-10\htmlreports\HTML_Report
    Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: here's the log from jenkins console output:

Comment: i cant attach file displaying the log. cant copy as well too long. anyone willing to assist?

Comment: Try to provide meaningful parts of your log.

Comment: hi i manage to edit the entire log from jenkins console output of the job. pls assist further. thnx in advance

Comment: any experts out there able to assist?

Comment: hi folks i able to fix after some testing here n there, change Google Chrome application location, by default after installaion Google folder will be at C:\Documents and Settings\SomeUserName\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application, copy out the entire Google folder to C:\Program Files and rerun the job at Jenkins and saw Chrome browser launch n ran the test as per the script. Hope my findings will be useful to many other who face similar problem. happy testing :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install chrome.

This gives it away: `cannot find Chrome binary`

If you already have chrome installed, then it can't find it.

On **linux**, try `whereis google-chrome`. If it brings up nothing, then you need to add google-chrome to your `$PATH`

On **windows**, try copying the entire Chrome folder to the default installation directory `C:\Program Files\`